# find average trajectory of movement vectors in R

Tags: r, geometry, trigonometry, spatial

I have a bunch of movement vectors with a direction (compass angle from 0-360), and velocity (km/hour, for example), and I want to summarize them into one average vector, and I can't seem to find a good way. Basically I want to be able to say "the average movement for this group is ___ degrees at ___ km/hour."

I've found some piecemeal ways to do it, but there has to be an easier way. I'm trying to scale this up, and it will eventually be applied to vectors not starting from the origin, and eventually vectors in geographic space (with CRS and stuff), so I'm trying to simplify as much as possible right now.

example code:

```
# data frame of vectors all starting at one origin with a compass angle and velocity
df <- data.frame(
  x=0, 
  y=0,
  # compass degrees where 0 is north and moves clockwise
  compassdegree = c(270,275,277,280,285,330, 40),
  velocity = c(2,2,2,2,1,1,1)
) %>%
  # we will plot with geom_spoke, which takes radians,
  # so some transformations are necessary 
  mutate(
    # convert to radian degrees:
    # (0 degrees points right from origin and goes counterclockwise)
    radiandegree = ((-compassdegree) + 450) %% 360 ,
    # convert from radiandegrees to radians
    radian = DescTools::DegToRad(radiandegree)) 

# plot the vectors 
plot <- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_spoke(aes(angle = radian, 
                 radius = velocity)) +
  coord_equal(xlim = c(-2,2),
                  ylim = c(-2,2))

plot


# find mean angle with circular::weighted.mean.circular
weighted.mean <- circular::weighted.mean.circular(
  x = circular::circular(df$radian, unit = "radians"),
  w = df$velocity
) %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  rename(radians = x) %>%
  # convert back to radian degrees, then to compass degrees
  mutate(radianDegree = circular::deg(radians),
         compassDegree = ((-radianDegree) + 450) %% 360 )


# alternatively, we could have used the radiandegrees 
# directly in the weighted.mean.circular function, but I'll still need it 
# in radians to plot, so this isn't really saving much 
weighted.mean2 <- circular::weighted.mean.circular(
  x = circular::circular(df$radiandegree, unit = "degrees"),
  w = df$velocity
) %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  rename(radianDegree = x) %>%
  # convert back to radian degrees, then to compass degrees
  mutate(compassDegree = ((-radianDegree) + 450) %% 360 )

# great, so now we have the average compassDegree: 286.85°, 
# but we still don't know the mean velocity


# try by finding endpoints of all original vectors, and finding the 
# centroid of them by summing all X and all Y values

# find endpoints of all vectors
df_endpoints <-  df %>%
  mutate(x_end = x + (velocity * cos(radian)),
         y_end = y + (velocity * sin(radian))) 

# find mean endpoint
mean_endpoint <- df_endpoints %>%
  summarize(x = mean(x_end),
            y = mean(y_end))

# find mean velocity by finding distance from averaged endpoint to origin
# using the pythagorean theorem
mean_vel <- sqrt(mean_endpoint$x^2 + mean_endpoint$y^2)
# now we have the mean velocity

plot + 
  geom_point(data = mean_endpoint,
            aes(x=x,y=y),
            color = "red", size = 2) +
  geom_spoke(aes(x = 0, y = 0, 
                 angle = weighted.mean$radians,
                 radius = mean_vel),
             color = "red", linetype = "longdash", size = .75)
```

[image]

Now we have the trajectories in black, and the average trajectory in red.

Is there not just a function that I can feed in a df of angles and velocities and receive this information (mean angle and mean velocity) directly out? Will the above method still apply when I move to spatial data (assuming I keep in mind distortion from projections and CRS)?

Comment: Would it suffice to take the average coordinate of the x and y coordinates of the endpoints of the vectors?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using the average x-y delta and converting that back to radians and velocity.

```
df_avg <- df %>%
  mutate(x_delta = velocity * cos(radian),
         y_delta = velocity * sin(radian)) %>%
  summarize(across(c(x, y, x_delta:y_delta), mean)) %>%
  mutate(velocity = sqrt(x_delta^2 + y_delta^2),
         radian = atan(y_delta/x_delta) + pi,
         src = "avg")

ggplot(bind_rows(df, df_avg),
       aes(x=x,y=y, color = src)) +
  geom_spoke(aes(angle = radian, 
                 radius = velocity)) +
  coord_equal(xlim = c(-2,2),
              ylim = c(-2,2))
```

[image]